# Unable to curl to external IP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am unable to curl to the external IP of the service. My Kubernetes cluster is deployed on GKE.

```
$ kubectl run kubia-container --image=australia/kubia_py --port=8080 --generator=run/v1
kubectl run --generator=run/v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
replicationcontroller/kubia-container created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME          READY  STATUS  RESTARTS  AGE
kubia-container-6b2cs  1/1   Running  0     25s

$ kubectl expose rc kubia-container --type=LoadBalancer --name kubia-http
service/kubia-http exposed

$ kubectl get pods,svc,rc
NAME            READY  STATUS  RESTARTS  AGE
pod/kubia-container-6b2cs  1/1   Running  0     93m

NAME         TYPE      CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)     AGE
service/kubernetes  ClusterIP   10.0.0.1   <none>     443/TCP     6h28m
service/kubia-http  LoadBalancer  10.0.4.238  35.188.42.26  8080:30030/TCP  91m

$ curl 35.188.42.26:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.188.42.26 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many ways to achieve what you want. I assume this image [australia/kubia_py](https://hub.docker.com/r/australia/kubia_py) it's your custom image. I think you are not able to curl this service as inside this image in file `nodeapp.py` you have put entry like:

```
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), GetHandler) 
print ("Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop") 
server.serve_forever()
```

Also if you would check `netstat` inside container you would see that its listening on `127.0.0.1:8080`

```
# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3
```

I think that instead of 'localhost' you should specify `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces.

I found only one way to achieve output of this [replicacontroller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) app (I suggest to try using [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) in the future) was using [web-preview](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview). To do that you would need to `port-forward` your pod.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubia-container-95rrq   1/1     Running   0          44m
user@cloudshell:~ (project-name)$ kubectl port-forward kubia-container-95rrq 8888:8080
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8888 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8888
Handling connection for 8888
```

Port `8888` was just one from default I choose. You have a few in menu.

And using `WebPreview` (using button from cloud shell). was able to achieve output like below:

```
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=('127.0.0.1', 46696) (127.0.0.1)
command=GET
path=/?authuser=0
real path=/
query=authuser=0
request_version=HTTP/1.1

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=BaseHTTP/0.6
sys_version=Python/3.6.9
protocol_version=HTTP/1.0
host_name=kubia-container-95rrq
host_ip=10.44.1.26
```

In addition, if you are exposing `replicacontroller` or `deployment` keep in mind if you will just set `--port=8080` it will also automatically set `--port-target` as `8080`. It's preferred if you are using `kubectl expose` to use flags `--port=XX` and `--target-port=xxxx`.

If you would like to check `kubia` `replicacontroller` and `service` you can use [this example](https://github.com/luksa/kubernetes-in-action/blob/master/Chapter09/kubia-rc-and-service-v1.yaml), like below:

```
$ kubectl apply -f kubia-rc-and-service-v1.yaml
replicationcontroller/kubia-v1 created
service/kubia created
user@cloudshell:~ (your-project)$ kubectl get rc,svc
NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicationcontroller/kubia-v1          3         3         3       40s

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.0.48.1     <none>           443/TCP          8h
service/kubia             LoadBalancer   10.0.51.154   35.240.23.237    80:30785/TCP     40s
$ curl 35.240.23.237:80
This is v1 running in pod kubia-v1-zpj6s
```

Another good example to expose service and access it you can find on [Official GKE docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `localhost:30030`, that's the nodeport exposed to your host.

If that doesn't work, it means your container is not listening in `8080`, you can test that entering the pod and curl `localhost:8080`.