# How to use external IP in gke

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I can't use the External IP of GKE
when i run kubectl get service it return:

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
hello        LoadBalancer   10.*****31    35.*****132   80:31388/TCP     25h
```

and bellow is my service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-lib
labels:
 app: hello-lib
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
selector:
 app: hello
ports:
 - port: 8000
 targetPort: 8000
 protocol: TCP
```

I created Firewall rules applies all ports and IP ranges:

[image: This is rule]

But when I connect to external IP by browser this returns a message:
"This site can’t be reached, Checking the proxy and the firewall"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with your GKE Service or Deployment. GKE automatically provision the Firewall rules required for the mapped ports to the service resources.

Expose exact ports on your service and map it to a correct port on your Deployment’s Pod. Firewalls required for the port 31888(nodeport) since this is load balancer to all Kubernetes nodes on TCP port.

**Please follow the below steps :**

- Check your service, Pod, Ingress are in the same namespace:using this command `kubectl get all -n staging`
- Check your Pod is listening on port 8xxx: run it locally if you can, or use `kubectl port-forward pods/[pod-name] -n staging 8xxx:8xxx` and try it locally with **http://localhost:8xxx/...**
- Check your [Service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer) is reaching your Pod correctly: use the command`kubectl port-forward service/testcompany-svc -n staging 8xxx:8xxx` and try it locally with **http://localhost:8xxx/...**
- Check any other Ingress spec rules before the one you posted
- Check for [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) in your VPC network, they should allow traffic from Google LBs

**Finally make sure you allow incoming traffic as follows below :**

From the internet To the load balancer on TCP port 8080.

From the load balancer To all Kubernetes nodes on TCP port 31388.

Also refer to this additional [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242293/unable-to-curl-to-external-ip), [Doc](https://pwittrock.github.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) for more information.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem of Chrome, when i run curl http://external-ip and this return Connection refused

Comment: @Otis, then please check the edit in the Answer.

Comment: My firewall is running but I  allowed TCP: 8080 and this port of the gke cluster

Comment: @Otis Based on your inputs edited the Answer.